# Send method as parameter to other class constructor and execute it

Tags: php, oop, constructor, anonymous-function

I have two class `A` and `B`

I want to 'send' a method from `A` to `B` via `B` constructor and then execute it in `B`. I've been trying to work with anonymous functions just like this :

```php
    class A 
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            // Send testMethod() to B with an anonymous function
            new B(function (string $test) {
                $this->testMethod($test);
            });
        }

        protected function testMethod(string $test) {
            echo ($test);
        }
    }


    class B 
    {
        protected $testFct;

        public function __construct($fctToExecute)
        {
            // Asign anonymous function to $testFct to be executed in all object
            $this->testFct= function (string $test) {
                $fctToExecute($test);
            };
        }

        // Want to be able now to call this $testFct function in a method like :
        protected function methodWhereICallTestfct() {
            $this->testFct("I'm dumb!"); // It has to echo "I'm dumb!"
        }        
    }
```

But when I try to set it up I get always an error like :

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method testFct()`

Do you have any idea what the problem is? I would like to specify that my php version is `PHP 7.1.3`.

**EDIT :**

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7da36485a8848a79f1334517c84eb506750a4a46) is it possible to see a more similare code as mine which return the error

Comment: Think I am missing something. How do you invoke this "test"? Show how you instantiate these. Also, what version of PHP?

Comment: is it complete code ?

Comment: @ficuscr I update it!

Comment: @Akhilesh Of course no it's just an example to understand the logic :)

Comment: So...`$foo = new A;`? How is this supposed to be used?

Comment: @ficuscr Sorry didn't say it. Actually `A` will be extend to an other class like `class otherClass extends A`. But normaly it has to work with `$foo = new A();`

Comment: Set up a fully functional example. That I can copy and paste. We are lazy devs for heavens sake :)  No errors -> http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4a9aa2394ea7c40f5934736f08115b68f86eaa5c

Comment: How you are trying to call a callable through a property does not work. PHP always looks for a method called `testFct`. If you are using PHP7, you can simply wrap the property access into parentheses and it will work. Otherwise assign the property to a local variable and then call the variable.

Comment: @ficuscr I recreate [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7da36485a8848a79f1334517c84eb506750a4a46) my error. Do you see the error ?

Comment: Another note: You need to import variables using `use` if you want to use them within the anonymous function.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank for your help! Do you have an example to `wrap the property access` or some docs to this concept because I don't really know what you mean with it

Comment: `($this->test)("hello world");`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Sorry first time that I see this type of notation. Or should I put it in the code above and what's special about it?

Comment: It's not a notation. We're simply giving PHP hints that the property access has a higher precedence than method execution (parens have a higher precedence). As I said we can achieve the same semantics by using a local variable to assign the property to.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for your time but will it be possible that you illustrate this on this [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7da36485a8848a79f1334517c84eb506750a4a46) ? To make sure I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got 2 mistakes in your code.

First mistake is that you ignore the parameter `$fctToExecute` in `B::__construct()`. If you would like to save the passed closure into a property of object `B` then you do not need another closure.

```
public function __construct(closure $fctToExecute) {
    // Asign anonymous function to $testFct to be executed in all object
    $this->testFct = $fctToExecute;
}
```

The second problem is that when you are trying to execute the closure you are actually trying to execute a function called `testFct`. You should use parentheses to declare precedence of operations.

```
$this->testFct("I'm dumb!"); // This looks for a function called testFct

($this->testFct)("I'm dumb!"); // This will execute the closure stored in the property called $testFct
```

The parentheses make a lot of difference here.